# Merge flat photos together

Tags: data-merge, merge

I have a series of images taken under a microscope. As the field of view isn't big enough I would like to merge all the pictures together.

I've tried with "Photo merge" under Photoshop but the result is ridiculously bad.

Any method to do this?

[image]

Comment: A few of these images don't seem to belong in the sequence (the last three). Maybe that's what's messing it up?  Also the images are not all the exact same exposure. Did you have them on auto exposure?  That's often a problem when trying to merge images.

Comment: I'd at least try to number them in some kind of logical order, top left > right; middle left > right; bottom left > right.... If a human has trouble telling what the sequence should be, then a computer will have no chance.

Comment: I also notice these are all somewhat low contrast. Maybe choose a brighter background. Automatic merging software may have difficulty with images like this.

Comment: I had a quick go chopping out the first 7 manually & setting them into logical order. There's still not enough info for Photomerge to figure out. Dragging lumps together afterwards produced this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTCds.png - which ain't exactly a work of art. I think it would benefit greatly from being less hand-held-wobbly & having much greater overlaps as well as better contrast. Having the same frame count per line i think would also help

Comment: Additionally, guestimating that bit of circuit at maybe 2cm across, you could probably get decent results with a regular DSLR & either a macro lens or even just a standard 50mm lens with a cheap extension tube. This is a quick hand-held shot, lit by torch (flashlight) to save me getting all the proper gear out. Low-qual jpg so it will post here but otherwise no post-processing, full size 24mp image, showing what I'm guessing are similar-sized components- https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIZRo.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Use a photo stitching program which lets you insert some known reference points. Photoshop goes astray if it guesses wrong and you have no way to help it. Check this overview of available software: https://expertphotography.com/best-photo-stitching-software/

At least Hugin allows user to insert common points to images.

BTW. Others have said your attached images are unsharp and have low contrast. They are right. Hopefully you have good quality versions available.